# Word automation service issues

Tags: iis, sharepoint-2010, word-automation, word-automation-service

I have issue with word Automation service. Permissions on DB which is hosted on SQL server are ok. There are no timeouts and errors on DB, verbose shows only this kind of log:

```
Database 'WordAutomation_01_SADB01': 
Connecting with connection string 'Data Source=XXXXXX;
Initial Catalog=WordAutomation_01_SADB01;
Integrated Security=True;
Enlist=False;
Connect Timeout=15'

App 'Word Automation Service 01': GetJobStatus complete: 00000000-0000-10a8-8031-1ce281d9f091; time = 518.00 ms

Proxy 'Word Automation Service 01 Proxy': GetJobStatus 00000000-0000-10a8-8031-1ce281d9f091 complete; time=15.00 ms
```

I have got 2 env~ `PROD` and `PREPROD`. It works on PROD but unfortunately not on preprod.

Any ideas where I should search issues?

Comment: Additionally, there are some suggestions to drop this service and install it again?

Comment: Whats more, this issue is related with nintex convert word document. Nintex workflow is "in progress" status for a 48h without any action.